# Combine multiple connections from the same NIC

Tags: networking, kernel, internet, vpn, network-bonding

My internet provider caps the internet on per ip basis. I can use multiple ip on the same NIC(Ethernet in my case) . I got this to work with downloads since I can segment my download over multiple ips. What I want to do is combine all the connections into one so I can use it for normal streaming and web surfing. The ip address providedby the ISP all belong to the same subnet(10.4.9.X) and all connect using a common WAN address.

I have searched quite a bit and found a software called Speedify. While it works for me , it is restricted to windows and is very costly. I want to do something similar by using a Ubuntu VPS with 1 gigabit link I have as the VPN part. I looked into channel bonding but most articles talk about bonding two different NICs from different WAN.

In short I have multiple ips on the same NIC and I want to use them all to connect to a my server. And then use all of them as a single connection.

PS. I am not looking for load-balancing solutions as I have already mentioned I have that figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to bond the virtual devices with broadcast option
(I'Ve never tried that, but you might give a try)

i.e.:

```
iface eth0:0 inet manual
        address  192.168.2.10
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        gateway  192.168.2.1
        dns-nameserver 192.168.2.1
        dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8

iface eth0:1 inet manual
        address  192.168.2.20
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        #gateway  192.168.2.1
        dns-nameserver 192.168.2.1
        dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
iface eth0:2 inet manual
        address  192.168.2.30
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        #gateway  192.168.2.1
        dns-nameserver 192.168.2.1
        dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
iface eth0:3 inet manual
        address  192.168.2.40
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        #gateway  192.168.2.1
        dns-nameserver 192.168.2.1
        dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        bridge_ports bond0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0


auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    bond-slaves eth0:0 eth0:1 eth0:2 eth0:3 eth0:4
    #Bond Mode have to be varied to check if this works
    bond-mode 4
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-updelay 200
    bond-downdelay 200
```

But i will not garantee that this might work, i only say this you can test this without any garantuee... I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS (i know i repeat me)

IF this Works, you can create devices as long your fingers wants

Hope my Idea worked for you